# Stop a position fixed div at a point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now I have it that if a user scrolls past the bottom of the side bar, then the sidebar turns to fixed and stays on the users page while they read the rest of the main content.

But now my fixed `div` is falling out into the footer. So, how can I stop it from falling out of the parent `div` and into the footer?

Here's a fiddle of what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/95W8w/

All the code is in jsFiddle, but since SO requires I put code here if I have a jsFiddle include.

**JavaScript:**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
 // Cache selectors for faster performance.
 var $window = $(window),
     $sidebar = $('#anchor'),
     $sidebarAnchor = $('#right');

 // Run this on scroll events.
 $window.scroll(function() {
var window_top = $window.scrollTop();
var div_top = $sidebarAnchor.offset().top;
if (window_top > div_top) {
 // Make the div sticky.
 $sidebar.addClass('stick');
 $sidebarAnchor.height($sidebar.height());
}
else {
    // Unstick the div.
    $sidebar.removeClass('stick');
    $sidebarAnchor.height(0);
  }
 });
```

});

Comment: i think u just have a style issue, try     position: fixed;
right: 0;
z-index: 4;
top: 0;

Comment: @anulik This just broke it way more.. haha.. IT's got to be with Javascript changing the class when the user scrolls x amount down the page

Answer (score 0):

Change `bottom` to `top` in your `.stick` class definition to make the sidebar stick to the top instead of bottom.

```
.stick {position: fixed; top:0px;}
```

Comment: Changing 'bottom' to 'top' makes your sticky sidebar stick to the top of the browser when scrolling (instead of the bottom). Maybe you could elaborate on your request if this does not address it.
http://jsfiddle.net/7Nzh6/